# Get shipping address county in Magento 2 observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, shipping, shipping-address

Hi I have a custom module . I want to get shipping country inside

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
```

Please let me know how can i get this?

I have seen this code for postcode , but i am not sure this is working or not

```
  $postCode = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()-getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
```

I need **shipping address country name** in public function execute. Please help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `sales_order_payment_save_after` event then in your observer, get address details as follow :

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var OrderPaymentInterface $payment */
        $payment = $observer->getDataByKey('payment');

        $order = $payment->getOrder();

        $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
        $city = $shippingAddress->getCity();
        $state = $shippingAddress->getRegion();
        $countryData = $this->countryInformation->getCountryInfo($shippingAddress->getCountryId());
        $country = $countryData->getFullNameLocale();
        return $this;
    }
```

Source: [link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/How-to-get-the-shipping-address-from-using-sales-order-payment/m-p/116093#M6668)

Comment: Please note this is on checkout page. Before placing order .

Comment: On the same page where you enter address details? I mean before going Next to Review and Payments section?

Comment: Really thank you for this . Could you please expand the answer buy giving sample code. Currently i have  
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    { } so inside this i have to write this new code

Comment: What event are you calling?

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: there is an error is coming.  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
Estimate Shipping and Tax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115784/discussion-between-abdulsamadabbasi-and-manik).